# Node Js call the function exported from the Js file through a javascript variable

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have stuck in calling the module function from a javascript variable.

server.js

```
const clevertap = require('./clevertap.js');
let endpoint = 'clevertap';//a test hardcoded value for reference
let result = {
{ "type": "event", "evtName": "Perso-reco"}
//what I need to do 
clevertap.log(result);
//what I tried 
endpoint.log(result);[endpoint].log(result);
```

clevertap.js

```
function log(message){
//do something
}
module.exports.log = log;
```

As the variable endpoint value is dynamic i can't hardcode it.

Comment: Set the `require` return value to the `clevertap` property of an object instead, then you can use object lookup, `obj[endpoint](msg)`

Comment: please explain me in detail

Comment: `const obj = { clevertap: require('./clevertap.js') };`

Comment: I have tried with the same it does not worked.Where you are calling log function with that.I got the error saying obj[endpoint] is not a function.

Comment: That defines an object - that doesn't call a function. Once the object is defined, you can look up variable properties on it, like the string in `endpoint`, to get a reference to the function and call it. `obj[endpoint](msg)`

Comment: If you get `obj[endpoint] is not a function` then the `endpoint` you have isn't a function property of the object

Comment: yes in my question only i defined endpoint as a variable.Its not a function.log() is my function here

Comment: You can use `eval(endpoint).log(result)` but using `eval` is not so good